# How to iterate over the bits of string?

Tags: c++, hamming-distance

I am trying to write a method to compute the bitwise hamming distance between two strings with an unknown length.

Is this possible and if so how would I do it? I have found some examples of how to do this with numeric types but I am not sure how to apply them to this problem.

Comment: This could mean the bitwise Hamming distance or the characterwise Hamming distance. I.e., you are looking at the total number of bits changed, or you are looking at the total number of characters changed. Example: `ATE` to `ARE` would have a bitwise distance of 2 (`T ^ R == 0110`), but only a characterwise distance of 1 (only the second character needed to change).

Comment: Are both strings guaranteed to be the same length? If not, how do you calculate the Hamming distance between two words of different lengths?

Comment: So the goal is to calculate the bitwise hamming distance. Regarding the length, both strings would be the same length but the length is unknown. Now that I am thinking about it a bit more this is obviously very simple, I could just check the size at the start of the method...

Comment: Or - if Hamming distance - is only an example of a distance measure - what should your measure consider? Also inserts of a character into the middle of the larger string or any combination of insert/delete/change and find the smallest number of operations needed?

Comment: Okay, both strings have the same length. Then it really is simple (as long as you decide, whether any changed character counts as 1 or the alphabetic distance or the bit distance of the character itself).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.